# How to apply a different texture to the Back face of the material in Reality Composer Pro?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, shader-graph, reality-composer-pro

I would like to apply different textures to the front and back faces of a 3D material. Specifically, when applying a texture that cuts the object in half through opacity, I want to be able to observe the back face of the object and apply a different color to it compared to the front face.

In Unity, there is a `isFrontFace` boolean node that allows for applying different colors to the front and rear faces. However, I am unsure of how to achieve the same effect in `Reality Composer Pro`!

3D Object of Cube here is already two-sided.

[ScreenShot of Shader Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUUkI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Reality Composer Pro currently doesn't have a built-in feature like Unity's "isFrontFace" node that directly allows applying different textures or colors to the front and back faces of a material.

- Use Shader Graph
- Double-Sided Materials
- Procedural Textures
- Geometry Split

Comment: there are a few workarounds you can try:

Comment: I have attached a link to the screenshot which illustrates my attempt to achieve same effect using Shader Graph. What am I missing?